# Is there any way that i can shorten this code?

Tags: vb.net, text, progress-bar, countdown

This is the code that i would like shortenning, it uses a progress bar and a label that counts down with it: I'm using the language of VB

```
 If ProgressBar1.Value = 33 And Label2.Text = "Now:  Hold down power button (3 seconds)" Then
            Label2.Text = "Now:  Hold down power button (2 seconds)"
        End If

        If ProgressBar1.Value = 66 And Label2.Text = "Now:  Hold down power button (2 seconds)" Then
            Label2.Text = "Now:  Hold down power button (1 seconds)"
        End If

        If ProgressBar1.Value = 99 And Label2.Text = "Now:  Hold down power button (1 seconds)" Then
            Label2.Text = "Now:  Hold down power button (0 seconds)"
        End If

        If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 And Label2.Text = "Now:  Hold down power button (0 seconds)" Then
            Label2.Text = "Now:  Also hold down the home button (10 seconds)"
            Label2.Location = New Point(30, Label2.Location.Y)
            Label3.Text = "Next:  Release the power button only (15 seconds)"
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
    Const BASE_MESSAGE As String = "Now:  Hold down power button ({0} seconds)"

    Select Case ProgressBar1.Value
       Case 33
          Label2.Text = String.Format(BASE_MESSAGE, 2)
       Case 66
          Label2.Text = String.Format(BASE_MESSAGE, 1)
       Case 99 
          Label2.Text = String.Format(BASE_MESSAGE, 0)

       Case 100
          Label2.Text = "Now:  Also hold down the home button (10 seconds)"
          Label2.Location = New Point(30, Label2.Location.Y)
          Label3.Text = "Next:  Release the power button only (15 seconds)"
          ProgressBar1.Value = 0

    End Select
```

Comment: Works perfectly apart from the end line that has two 'end' commands. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @user1081679: Sorry about that, I have fixed the answer. Also, welcome to Stackoverflow! Remember that when an answer solves or helps you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark and up arrow next to the question to let future visitors to the question know this is what solved your problem.